# Access all usb from docker container in docker native osx

Tags: macos, docker, native, beta

I've just installed docker native support for osx. How can i share all usbs to the container?

I want to do the same thing what is done by running privileged container with volume `/dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb` on docker in *debian*. I don't want to use `--device` argument.

Thanks.